# Understanding parent nodes when removing node from BST

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to remove a node from a BST and I actually got the code to work but there is one part of it I do not understand. This is my code:

```
class BST {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }

  remove(value, parentNode = null) {
    let currentNode = this;
    while (currentNode !== null) {
      if (value < currentNode.value) {
        parentNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.left;
      } else if (value > currentNode.value) {
        parentNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.right;
      } else {
        if (currentNode.left !== null && currentNode.right !== null) {
          currentNode.value = currentNode.right.getMinValue();
          currentNode.right.remove(currentNode.value, currentNode);
        } else if (parentNode === null) {
          if (currentNode.left !== null) {
            currentNode.value = currentNode.left.value;
            currentNode.right = currentNode.left.right;
            currentNode.left = currentNode.left.left;
          } else if (currentNode.right !== null) {
            currentNode.value = currentNode.right.value;
            currentNode.left = currentNode.right.left;
            currentNode.right = currentNode.right.right;
          }
        } else if (parentNode.left === currentNode) {
          parentNode.left = currentNode.left !== null ? currentNode.left : currentNode.right;
        } else if (parentNode.right === currentNode) {
          parentNode.right = currentNode.left !== null ? currentNode.left : currentNode.right;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    return this;
  }

  getMinValue() {
    let currentNode = this;
    while (currentNode.left !== null) {
      currentNode = currentNode.left;
    }
    return currentNode.value;
  }
}
```

I use the `getMinValue` method for the edge case where I have to remove a node with two children nodes. I use that method to replace the current node's value (the one that I'm removing) with the lowest value from the right subtree of that node. I then call the `remove` method to remove that same node from the right subtree.

What I don't understand is the following line:

```
currentNode.right.remove(currentNode.value, currentNode);
```

I know that this line is removing the node that was used as a replacement for the base node but I don't understand why I have to pass the `currentNode` as the parentNode argument.
Won't the remove method have to find the node that needs to be removed first and hence change the `parentNode` value anyways? Why can't I just make that argument `null`?

Comment: If `while (currentNode !== null) {...`? if so, one of the first 2 conditions would be true ? if so, then `parentNode = currentNode;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm keeps track of `parentNode` as it descends through the tree so that it can set the `parentNode.left` or `parentNode.right` property to `null` whenever `currentNode` turns out to be the node to be removed.

Now when you call `remove` again in the case you describe, you also need to pass on a reference for `parentNode`, as it might be that this `currentNode.right` is a node without left child, and thus is the one that needs to be removed. For that removal to happen, its parent node needs its `right` property to be set to `null`, and so a reference to it is needed.

If you would pass `null` for that parameter it would work fine in cases where `currentNode.right` has a left child -- you would descend further down and so set `parentNode` appropriately. But for the case where it doesn't have a left child, it is *that* node that needs to be removed, and so we need to know its parent.

Comment: That made a lot of sense the way you explained it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`parentNode` is needed when the node being removed is the root of the subtree. In this case, the appropriate child link in the parent has to be updated to point to the corresponding child of the node being removed.

When `parentNode === null`, it means you're removing the top-most node in the entire BST, so there's no parent to update. You can't use that code path when you're removing a node in the middle of the tree.